# A nested array schema with object element returns an array with empty object

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I want to have array of objects i.e teamMembers should be an array and should have object as its element with properties name and role.I do not receive any error, when I console.log(req.body), its in the format i want, but the the array element which is object is not be posted to the schema.

````
  _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  teamName: { type: String, unique: true },
  teamMembers: {
    name: {
      type: String, unique: true, lowercase: true, required: true
    },
    role: {
      type: String,
      enum: ['goal keeper', 'central back', 'central midfield', 'central forward', 'left wing',
        'attacking midfield', 'central forward', 'left midfielder', 'striker', 'defending', 'right midfielder'],
      required: true
    },
    type: Array
  },
  description: String,
  createdAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now() },
  updatedAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now() }
});

teamSchema.plugin(uniqueValidator); ```


I am not getting the desired result. Here is my collection from mogodb
````

```
{
"_id":{"$oid":"5d89d5da3f33f36579bfed25"},
"teamMembers":[{}],
"createdAt":{"$date":{"$numberLong":"1569314251247"}},
"updatedAt":{"$date":{"$numberLong":"1569314251247"}},
"teamName":"Arsenal",
"__v":{"$numberInt":"0"}
}
```

````
Expected result
``` "teamMembers":[{"name": "bernd leno", "role": "goal keeper"}] ```

Gotten result ``` "teamMembers":[{}] ```

Here is my below

```static async addTeam(req, res) {
    const {
      teamName, teamMembers, description
    } = req.body;
    try {
      if (!req.user.isAdmin) {
        return response(res, 404, 'error', {
          message: messages.unAuthorizedRoute
        });
      }
      const teams = new TeamModel({
        _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
        teamName,
        teamMembers,
        description
      });
      const team = await teams.save();
      if (team) {
        return response(res, 201, 'success', { team });
      }
    } catch (error) {
      (error.errors.teamName.name === 'ValidatorError')
        ? response(res, 409, 'error', {
          message: messages.duplicateName
        })
        : response(res, 400, 'error', {
          message: messages.error
        });
    }
  }```
````

Comment: `teamMembers: { name, role },` - That's **not** an array and basically I see no valid attempt in your code to add the expected array content. Additionally the schema is incorrect for an *array* of objects on that property. Should instead be `teamMembers: [{ name: String, role: { ..all of your stuff.. } }]` and *that* is a definition for an array of objects with those two defined properties.

Comment: Also **extremely importantly** is you **do not want unique** set on an array member. This actually means a **unique index for the collection**, and does not mean *unique in array* as you seem to presume it does. Array *uniqueness* in MongoDB is not enforced by indexes. This will only cause problems since you very likely expect that property to be present in more than one document of the collection, even if you want it *unique* within the array of a single document.

Comment: Please use the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58076844/edit) on your question for additional details or corrections. Comments are not the place for these.

Comment: The teamModel I posted is correct, since I indicated type as an Array, ```teamMembers: {
    name: {
      type: String, unique: true, lowercase: true, required: true
    },
    role: {
      type: String,
      enum: ['goal keeper', 'central back', 'central midfield', 'central forward', 'left wing',
        'attacking midfield', 'central forward', 'left midfielder', 'striker', 'defending', 'right midfielder'],
      required: true
    },
    type: Array //type is an array... This is scalable
  }``` After many console.log, I realized the name and role parameter are undefined

Comment: The problem I am facing right now is how to post the array object from post man. This is not working for me because req.body.name and req.body.role will be undefined ```"teamMembers": [{"name": "bernd leno", "role":"goal keeper"}]```

Answer (score 0):

My code is correct, I wasn't posting the array of objects correctly from postman.[Right way to post an array of objects in postman using urlencoded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HQwYC.png)

It also works with raw json/urlencoded

```
{
    "teamName": "Arsenal",
    "teamMembers": [{"name": "bernd leno", "role":"goal keeper"}, {"name": "Emiliano Martinez", "role":"goal keeper"}]
}
```